# Boolean modifier just remove my object

Tags: modifiers

I wanted to apply a modifier between two cones. Here is what you can see before I make it visible:

[image]

and after:

[image]

As you can see, the bigger cone just disapeared. I tried to update the normals (Shift-N in edit mode or Mesh > Normal > Recalculate outside) of both the small and the large cone, still the same issue. Actually, the cone disappear even if I use union!

Also, to make sure that the pointy vertex is not removed, I made sure to shift a bit the smaller cone:

[image]

Here is the file: http://www.filedropper.com/01problememodifier

-- EDIT --

I also tried to intersect these two shapes:
[image]

and here is the result (fast mode):
[image]

In exact mode, I see nothing... **but if I click on self, it works**!
[image]

Comment: Try turning the boolean modifier from exact to fast, sometimes that fixes it.

Comment: @NascentSpace I tried it but it's not working...

Comment: for me using fast worked, BUT I needed to move second object some, to make it intersect "simpler"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turns out that I just need to click on "self" on the modifer, no idea why it's not checked by default:

[image]

**EDIT:** as pointed out in the comment, the problem may be instead that the shape had double vertices (created when I turned the cylinder into a cone by scaling one side). Therefore, it may also be enough to remove doubles vertices (Edit mode > Mesh > Merge > By distance), thanks!

Comment: FYI the reason why it doesn't work is because you have double vertices. In edit mode select everything > Right click > Merge > by distance

Comment: Really? Why do I have double vertices? Is the top of the cone considered as a multiple vertex? Thanks for the information. An any idea why self solves that?

Comment: It depends on how you created the cone : Did you use a modifier or the spin tool ? I don't know about the self parameter, it may force the evaluation with "welded" vertices even if they are not actually welded...

Comment: For the cone, I started from a cylinder, and I scaled to 0 one side.

Comment: All the vertices from the side you scaled to 0 were on the exact same coordinates. visually you see only one vertex but they are actually several at the very same spot

Comment: Ok, I would not expect that to be a problem. I guess blender should maybe display a warning in that case, or automatically remove multiple vertices. It's quite strange to get two very different results depending on the presence of an invisible object.

Comment: I had the same problem changing to fast from exact solved the problem for me.
[![From Exact To Fast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdp0u.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdp0u.jpg)